# Qemu connecting to specific guest UART device

Tags: serial-port, arm, qemu, uart

I emulate the firmware of a embedded device with qemu-system-arm. The output of the console is working fine by appending "console=ttyAMA0" to the kernel. On the guest there is a binary which opens another serial port for communication (bi-directional) on /dev/ttyGS0 and listens on that port. Now I need to connect to this port from the host, to send commands to the binary and receive the output.

I already tried different things like creating character devices and pseudo ttys, but I don't know how to define the serial device for the guest.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass multiple -serial options to QEMU they will be interpreted as defining what you want to do for UARTs 0, 1, 2, etc. So for example "-serial stdio -serial tcp::4444,server" will send UART 0 to your terminal and connect UART 1 to a TCP server on port 4444 which you can then connect to with netcat or similar utility. (You can connect serial output to a lot of different backends, not just stdio or TCP: check the QEMU documentation.)

(NB: this relies on your board model actually creating multiple UARTs and wiring them up to the command line options correctly, of course.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I look at my /dev/ on the guest it lists at least six UART devices: ttyACM0, ttyAMA0, ttyAMA1, ttyAMA2, ttyAMA3 and ttyGS0. According to your answer, I need to add the -serial option six times where the last one is the serial for ttyGS0?

Comment: That depends on your board model. You should look at the documentation or implementation of it, which is a more reliable indication of what serial devices are actually present than what the guest OS happens to have probed or to think might exist.

Comment: Mh okay, I use the vexpress-a9 machine type, but the real board is unknown to me. I will have a look if I can determine which port is used.

Comment: The vexpress-a9 has 4 PL011 UARTs. As a general rule if you have guest code that wants to run on a particular piece of hardware it's not going to work very well if you try to run it on something else. ttyGS0 here is the USB "gadget serial driver", and there is no implemented USB h/w on vexpress-a9. You can probably fudge it into working by setting up the '/dev/ttyGS0' node to really be a ttyAMA1 or something (which would be the 2nd pl011 on the vexpress.)